# Button on click reactjs and styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

My styled component:

```
const Button = styled.button
  /* Adapt the colors based on primary prop */
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "grey" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "grey"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;`
```

And this is my return

```
 return (

  <div className="App">

    <Button >Lunch</Button>
    <Button primary>Dinner</Button>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

the button look like this [the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqLQY.jpg) when the button "Lunch" click design button swap with "Dinner", how to make button onclik (like button active and inactive), i'm newbie with reactjs and styled-component.

Comment: your style component looks good. What do you mean with swap? Lunch gets Dinner style and vice versa?

Comment: you can have a ternary operator for adding that "primary" attribute, so when "Lunch" button is clicked toggle the styling and apply it to the "Dinner" btn and vice versa.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MohitArora what the mean ternary operator ?, and i mean what is it ?, haha i really dun no

Comment: @dipretelin check the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

You can use ternary operator to evaluate a condition and perform what action has to be performed when condition evaluates to true or false. In your case you can apply the color to button

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto yes that's it , when `<Button >Lunch</Button>` clik the button look text "white", background "grey" and `<Button primary>Dinner</Button>` this button outline "grey" and text "grey"

Comment: ok, i just didnt understand if this behavior it's happening or if you want to happen it.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto i want to happen it , pls help me , haha